# Issues Accessing SOAP service with Python

Tags: python, soap, python-requests

I am attempting to access the NJTransit API, I have successfully queried it using the Postman application but no matter what I try I cannot get python to successfully return the desired query.
Using suds:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://traindata.njtransit.com:8090/NJTTrainData.asmx?wsdl"
client = Client(url, cache = None)
from suds.sax.element import Element
auth = Element('UserCredentials')
auth.append(Element('userName').setText(my_username))
auth.append(Element('password').setText(my_password))
client.set_options(soapheaders = auth)
client = Client(url, cache = None)
result = client.service.getTrainScheduleJSON("NY")
```

This results in "none".

I've also attempted to use the preformatted request suggested by the Postman app, however I keep getting a 404 error.

```
import requests

url = "http://traindata.njtransit.com:8090/NJTTrainData.asmx"

querystring = {"wsdl":""}

payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Header>\n    <UserCredentials xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/webservices/\">\n      <userName>---</userName>\n      <password>---</password>\n    </UserCredentials>\n  </soap:Header>\n  <soap:Body>\n      <getTrainScheduleJSON xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/webservices/\">\n      <station>NY</station>\n    </getTrainScheduleJSON>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
headers = {
    'content-type': "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    'host': "traindata.njtransit.com",
    'soapaction': "http//microsoft.com/webservices/getTrainScheduleJSON"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help/insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never want to set the "Host" header, this is will be done by requests.

The 404 is triggered by the wrong SOAPAction. There is a missing : after http.

The following snippet is working fine for me.

```
import requests

url = "http://traindata.njtransit.com:8090/NJTTrainData.asmx"

querystring = {"wsdl":""}

payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Header>\n    <UserCredentials xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/webservices/\">\n      <userName>---</userName>\n      <password>---</password>\n    </UserCredentials>\n  </soap:Header>\n  <soap:Body>\n      <getTrainScheduleJSON xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/webservices/\">\n      <station>NY</station>\n    </getTrainScheduleJSON>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
headers = {
    'content-type': "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    'soapaction': 'http://microsoft.com/webservices/getTrainScheduleJSON'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print response
print(response.text)
```